# Force close on loading image from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My activity force closed if I quickly scroll down the recyclerview that contain a lot of images. I use firebase storage to load the images. Here is the error log:

```
28-20869/com.example.rizkafs.laundrize E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzax(Z)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.example.rizkafs.laundrize-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes7.dex)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.onCanceled(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-14 13:45:12.642 20628-20869/com.example.rizkafs.laundrize E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseStorage-Download-2
                                                                               Process: com.example.rizkafs.laundrize, PID: 20628
                                                                               java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzax(Z)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.example.rizkafs.laundrize-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes7.dex)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.onCanceled(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rizkafs.laundrize"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Do you think it has problem with my gradle? Let me now when you know the answer, Thank You.

Comment: can you post your Gradle file

Comment: Do you use proguard?

Comment: @AkhileshPatil I have edited my post, there is my gradle file.

Comment: @Henry Yes, I use proguard.

Comment: post your code as well in which u r getting the the force close that Log only does not make sense clearly.

Comment: @ArnabKundu There's no class of his project in the stacktrace, it's just google play services that produce the stacktrace.